# How to Restrict Content OVerview to certain content types for user roles

Tags: nodes

I have a user role called Athletics and I have given these users access to add, edit or delete the content type Athletes. However when the content type is created it just creates a node not a URL alias so the Athletics users can not navigate to a page to edit or delete. I tried giving access to the content overview but I think that would confuse my non-technical users. Is there a way to make it so they can ONLY see the content they can edit or delete within the content overview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) will replace the admin listing pages with views, and then you can tweak it.

But looking at your question in the greater context what you really need is [Contextual Admnistration](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views). With it you can create a admin UI for your athletics role to manage content. There is a video tutorial series on Youtube.